# What's the correct term for a waitress in the Middle Ages?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, women

How was a waitress called in the Middle Ages? Handmaid, waitress, maid, ...? And is there a different name for the ones who did this kind of job inside a castle, in contrast to the women doing this kind of job in, for example, a tavern?

Comment: Is there any evidence that waitresses existed in the middle ages?  And in which country?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Well, someone served the food.

Comment: But if there were no commercial establishments, then the person who served teh food was a wife or household servant.  "waitress" only has meaning in a commercial establishment. Although there has been some recent revision, my memory estimates that less than 1% of the population traveled and probably 90% of them would stay in the homes of friends.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, agree in general, but I bet there were some kind of pubs for the locals in most of the places. Just to gather around and socialize.

Comment: Good theory; how would we test it?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace There were Inns, where travellers would stop to rest their horses (or, in some cases, change horses) and you could rent a room for the night and buy food to eat.  For example, the Cott Inn in Cott, Dartington, Devon, England, dates from 1320 (i.e. late medieval), but Inns have existed since Roman times.

Comment: Of course there were [inns](https://www.thrillist.com/travel/nation/17-of-the-oldest-hotels-in-the-world-nishiyama-onsen-keiunkan-tops-our-list) and [pubs](https://www.thedrinksbusiness.com/2014/11/10-of-the-worlds-oldest-pubs/) back then.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I believe OP implicitly asks for English language answers (as it’s an English language site), so the region must be England. I also think they’re mostly interested in later part of Middle Ages, when English language became more or less recognizable for modern speakers.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, by checking if we have such places depicted in period art/documents and having archeological evidences. And for *some regions* and *some historical periods* we can do that.

Comment: [Here's](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43758/were-there-inns-and-hostels-in-medieval-europe) a good existing thread with some links.

Comment: @Neith: The jump from "this site's language is English" to "the question must be about England" is a quite big (and invalid) one. The question being about an English *term* is more telling.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the top of my head, I remember the word [wench](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wench), which originally meant girl, then a servant, and later also a prostitute, which is likely why it went out of use for waitresses.

Here’s a somewhat confirming [article](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/os-xpm-1988-05-24-0040230028-story.html) from 1988. (If link is blocked for you, use [Wayback Machine copy](http://web.archive.org/web/20190601163319/https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/os-xpm-1988-05-24-0040230028-story.html).) It describes the job of a wench at Medieval Times, a “dinner theater” which still exists ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_Times), [Official site](https://www.medievaltimes.com)). So, even if it’s a misconception, the idea that medieval waitresses were called wenches at least exists in modern mass conscience.

Comment: Is 'wench' really confirmed to be in use in medieval England? This 'conforming article' is link only and already broken, in this case geo-blocked. Please quote the most relevant parts here.

Comment: @LangLangC While not a medieval example, the Elizabethan poet [Sir Philip Sidney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_Sidney) used it in one of his poems a mere 100 years later:  *"I, like a tẽder harted wench, shriked out for feare of the divell."*, or Shakespeare in "Alls Well that Ends Well" (Act IV, sc. 3): "*he weeps like a wench that had shed her milk*" in 1604

Comment: Most likely, original "waitresses" were just children of the owner, so, probably, in every language it would be something like usual word for `girl` or `boy` at that era.

Comment: @LangLangC I added a description.

Comment: OED has "wench" in the sense of "girl" from 1290, expanding to "serving-maid" from 1380, so it's plausible. Either way, the term certainly does exist in "modern mass conscience", though it has an almost humorous, parody-like quality now...

Comment: I think you mean "consciousness" rather than "conscience".

Comment: @LangLangC [Yes, it was a Middle English word](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED52198): variants include *wenche* and *weinche*. That said, it was just a word for "girl" (from *wenchel*, 'tot'), used as a term of address.

Comment: @Acccumulation I looked into Wikipedia article “Collective consciousness” and it presents these variants as synonyms. You may edit my answer if you feel it’s needed.

Comment: Your link to orlandosentinel.com is blocked in the EU.

Comment: @AliceRyhl I’ve added Wayback machine link.

Comment: 'Wench' just means 'girl'. *Serving-wench* means waitress.

Comment: AFAIK, *wench* was used for any youngish unmarried female, much the same way *girl* is/was before PC caught up. So - "the girl behind the till"; (employee) "the girl's broken the china" (servant); "my girl's left me" (lover);  "I love my girls" (daughter). Also, I *believe* that **youth** originally meant any young person, irrespective of gender

Comment: While this site is written in English, this answers turns the question into "what were called waitresses in Middle-Age England?" I guess that's what the OP wanted, since they have selected it, but it changes the question without being a frame challenge.

Answer (score 27):

> [What] was a waitress called in the Middle Ages?

In Europe, they didn't exist as a recognized occupation.

> And is there a different name for the ones who did this kind of job inside a castle, in contrast to the women doing this kind of job in, for example, a tavern?

At a castle, the servants in the [great hall](http://www.castlesandmanorhouses.com/life_01_rooms.htm#hall) would simply be servants (pre-Conquest, **[þrǣl](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED45428/track?counter=1&search_id=1091146)**, **[ancilla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ancilla#Latin)**, &c.; post-Conquest, **[servaunt](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52908/whats-the-correct-term-for-a-waitress-in-the-middle-ages)**, **[bond-womman](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED5508/track?counter=1&search_id=1091146)**, **[ancille](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED1531)**, **[natif](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED29116/track?counter=1&search_id=1091256)**, &c.) and the [traditional breakdown of roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_household#Composition) concerned production and maintenance, not presentation. A large enough household would have separate departments for the table linen ([napery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napery)), drinking vessels ([ewery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ewery)), alcohol ([buttery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buttery_(room))), lighting ([chandlery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandlery)), &c. and various aspects of the food ([larder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larder#History), [spicery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spicery), [saucery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saucery), &c.). The guys who carried the food to the table from whatever department were just "bearers" (**[ber(e)-man](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4154/track?counter=3&search_id=1091434)** and **[ber-knight](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4184)**). In Middle English, "[waiter](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED51535/track?counter=1&search_id=1091484)" meant "watchman".

Pubs don't seem to be attested between the Romans and [the late 10th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pub#Origins_and_history), when there were enough *ealahuse*s to show up in [Æthelred the Unready](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86thelred_the_Unready)'s legal code. Breweries aren't attested as professional before the Central European monasteries [in the 11th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brewery#History). Inns were few and far between, with most travelers obliged to seek hospitality from the churches & monasteries.

If women were doing the serving instead of the men, especially if they were hired help or servants instead of daughters, their morals would've been highly suspect. Cleaning their depravity up would've fallen on the local lord; some, like [the bishops of Winchester](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/history/london-graveyard-s-become-memorial-citys-seedier-past-180953104/), were content to let 'single women' serve men to [prevent more unnatural sins like masturbation](https://thetemplarknight.com/2012/09/09/the-winchester-geese-medieval-prostitution/) and to skim the girls' earnings.

In any case, there wasn't a specialist term for "waitress", although you could *coin* "bearwoman" and "bearmaid". Instead, they would've used one of twenty-odd words for "hey you **girl**" (e.g., [wench](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED52198/track?counter=1&search_id=1091132), [maide](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED26497/track?counter=1&search_id=1091422), [therne](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED45178), [shelcherne](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED39832), &c.) or "**servant woman**" (e.g., ancille, [slutte](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED41008/track?counter=13&search_id=1091422), [malkin](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED26675), [ber-wif](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED4214), &c.) or some local slang like the "Winchester geese" who worked in the bishops' "stews".

Comment: This answer ends the Middle Ages in the 11th century, it lasted much more than that. There were certainly more travelers in the 14th-15th centuries than in the 11th, and therefore more inns.

Comment: "Winchester geese" were prostitutes, not serving women.

Comment: @vsz Mentioning that the entire industry didn't properly exist before the 11th century doesn't limit the era and words for servants in Middle English are mentioned and usages are available via link. When you've got a bit, swot up on your reading comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

The question does not specify the language, so...  at least to refute the highly accepted answer there were no such establishments in the Middle Ages.

Old Czech word *hospoda* or *hostinicě* - German *Obdach, Herberge, Wirtshaus* - Latin *hospitium* - inn, pub
*šenk*, *krčma* - German *Schenke*, *Wirtshaus* - Latin *caupona* - rather a place to drink than to sleep

for the proffession:

*šenk* - from German Schenk, Mundschenk, Hofschenk - **[a cup bearer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup-bearer)** - , it was an office, the King of Bohemia was the Erzmundschenk, the Cup-bearer of the Emperor of the Holy-roman empire

the personal of normal inns or pubs:
masc. *krčmář*, fem. *krčmářka* or
masc. *šenkéř*, fem. *šenkéřka*, obviously from German *Schenkwirt*, not an office but a proffession, it may be the owner, his wife or an employee

Answer (score 0):

An English popular song (printed in the 16th century but no doubt earlier than that) gives one politically incorrect answer:

```
He that will an alehouse keep
  Must have three things in store;
A chamber and a feather bed
  A chimney and a... hey nonny nonny no...
```

"Wench" is the wrong 5-letter word beginning with "w" here :)

Scan of a published version in 1611: http://www.pbm.com/~lindahl/ravenscroft/melismata/mel33small.html

Comment: I don’t think “whore” ever meant waitress.

Comment: Which is fine as it goes: the serving girls were either the keep's daughters and/or 'working girls'. That said, it's still not the word for the girls as servants.

Comment: The job didn't exist. It was done by men, not women if it was even done at all. The earliest attestation of "waiter" referring to a public eating house as opposed to a private house is in the 1660sm which is not "the middle ages". The word "waitress" didn't appear until the 19th century.

Comment: @alephzero That is a very strange claim. I can find loads of mentions of qomen serving (possibly being the owners) in pubs in the Kingdom of Bohemia in the 16th century.  It was a quick search on a mobile phone. I would be surprised if it didn't go much farther back in history.

Answer (score -2):

You could try "Pot Girl".

From https://www.yourdictionary.com/pot-girl.

"A girl who works serving customers in an inn or public house".

Comment: When was that used? In what country?

Comment: Certainty British

Comment: The term is probably of recent origin though, according to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pot-girl).

Comment: [Pot girl](https://oed.com/view/Entry/148724) isn't attested until the 18th century.

Comment: A pot girl washes pots.